# How to set Hashmap value using model class

Tags: java, database, class, model, hashmap

I want to set Hashmap value using data from database and set it in model class, it doesn't work yet and shows empty data. Here is my code, get Data from database

```
private ArrayList<Kategori> categories;
private ArrayList<ChatRoom> chatroom_list;
private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ChatRoom>> chatrooms;

void getDataList(){
    categories = new ArrayList<>();
    chatrooms = new HashMap<>();
    chatroom_list = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        categories.clear();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM kategori ORDER BY id ASC", null);
        //cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM chatroom ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ", null);
        Kategori kategori;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            kategori = new Kategori();
            kategori.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            kategori.setNama(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nama")));
            categories.add(kategori);
        }
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        chatroom_list.clear();
        chatrooms.clear();
        ChatRoom chatRoom;
        for (int i=0;i<categories.size();i++){
            cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM chatroom WHERE status = '0' ORDER BY id ASC", null);
            while (cursor2.moveToNext()){
                chatRoom = new ChatRoom();
                chatRoom.setId(cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndex("id")));
                chatRoom.setNama(cursor2.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nama")));
                chatRoom.setDosen(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("dosen")));
                chatRoom.setInfo(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("info")));
                chatRoom.setId_kategori(cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndex("id_kategori")));
                if(categories.get(i).getId()==chatRoom.getId_kategori())
                    chatroom_list.add(chatRoom);
            }
            chatrooms.put(categories.get(i).getId(), chatroom_list);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I check it, Hashmap just shows empty data, Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of calling `clear()` on a new collection?

Comment: Can you check that the categories has any elements?! If yes, can you check that there is any data are returned back after you query to db?! I think just step by step like that to figure out the issue. Hope this help.

Comment: to ensure that arraylist is empty when it used firstly, that arraylist and hashmap will be called when database has been updated

Comment: yap Kenny i've checked it, categories works correctly, there's no error there, how to check the hashmap value if the data type is a kind of class model like that

Comment: @reed: you just need to get the Key Set or the List Values and check the size or iterator it to check the values.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your bug is here:

```
if(categories.get(i).getId()==chatRoom.getId_kategori())
    chatroom_list.add(chatRoom);
```

I guess getId() returns `Integer`, which is an object. Comparing objects with `==` fails in most cases. When it comes to `Integer`, it fails once the value is under -128 or over 127 (though this can be overriden. Also there are other circumstances when comparing integers using `==` can like magically fail or succed. Just don't do it).

Anyhow. Check if `getId()` returns `Integer` or `Long`. If so, change it to `categories.get(i).getId().equals(chatRoom.getId_kategori())`